# Displaying current time adjusting for Timezone

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My database stored all dates in utc format.  When displaying the date on forms, I use code like this:

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);        
 var displayTime = item.Timestamp.AddHours(ts.Hours);
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => displayTime)
```

My server is on west coast, I think (shared server).  When I display results from above, it shows 1 hour behind, presumable due to Daylight Savings time.  When I read the description of GetUtcOffset, it appears that that method should adjust for DST.

I also tried:

```
  TimeZoneInfo tzl = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
   var displayTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(item.Timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, tzl);
```

Same result.

What am I missing?